# Stopping clearInterval from child's if

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble stopping my function. I've read the other suggested questions and answers and have done extensive searching.

How do I stop the timer? I've tried to overwrite the variable from the child to no avail.

```
timer = setInterval(function() {
  spawnAlien();
  var alienCollision =  collision($("#orb"), $("#alienDiv"));
    console.log(alienCollision);
    if (alienCollision === true) {
    ($("#orb"), $("#alienDiv")).detach();
    clearInterval(timer)};
}, 33);
```

I have the whole code [here](http://jsbin.com/farikufewe/edit?html,css,js,console,output) the error shows itself in console

Comment: What is problematic about it?

Comment: Thanks, that makes the code a little cleaner but doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one semicolon en of this line clearInterval(timer).
now I try it in your jsbin and its worked...

```
timer = setInterval(function() {
  spawnAlien();
  var alienCollision =  collision($("#orb"), $("#alienDiv"));
    console.log(alienCollision);
    if (alienCollision === true) {
    ($("#orb"), $("#alienDiv")).detach();
    clearInterval(timer); // here you missed the semicolon ;
};
}, 33);
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, I added the semicolon but it still returns an error rather than stopping the timer

Comment: @user10101 can you provide me a sample output

Comment: By output do you mean the consolelog? If so, [here](http://jsbin.com/maborejalo/edit?html,console). I'm trying to remove the divs when they collide, then start a timer to 'respawn' the alien div after adding a point to a score variable.